# Is it possible to check if the current route change is a redirect rule?

Tags: angularjs, routes, route-provider

I created an angular module that uses the current $location.path to load content dynamically. I set up the module config like this:

```
var app = angular.module('App',['ngRoute']).
config(
    ['$routeProvider','$locationProvider','$sceProvider'],
    function($routeProvider,$locationProvider,$sceProvider){
        $routeProvider.
            otherwise({
                templateUrl: 'views/_view.html',
                controller: 'ViewCtr',
                resolve: {
                    load: function(dataFactory,$route,$location){
                        return dataFactory.load($location.path());
                    }
                }
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $sceProvider.enabled(false);
});
```

It works perfectly although when I set $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart') to add some animations when content is loading, it fires the route change twice. I believe it's because I set the routeProider as "otherwise" and it redirects every time.

Can you correct me if I am wrong or tell me if and how it is possible to differentiate from a real route change and a redirect? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to using $routeChangeSuccess instead of $routeChangeStart. I would also look into ng-animate (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) as it will probably be able to handle it better then you listening in for routeChanges.

Comment: The only problem is that I want two animations to show. One when the route change starts and another one when it succeeds or errors.